"Sum of functions" terminology
The following is a sanity check.
Given two functions $f_1:X\rightarrow Y$ and $f_2:X\rightarrow Y$, the sum of $f_1$ and $f_2$ typically refers to $(f_1+f_2):X\rightarrow Y$ with $(f_1+f_2)(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x)$.
Now, say I have $f_1:X_1\rightarrow Y$ and $f_2:X_2\rightarrow Y$ and define the function $g:X_1\times X_2\rightarrow Y$ with $g(x_1,x_2)=f_1(x_1)+f_2(x_2)$.
My questions:

Sanity check part: this function $g$ is well defined assuming $f_1$ and $f_2$ are well defined, right?
What would one call the function $g$? I first referred to $g$ as the sum of two functions but I suppose this is a little misleading as it is not the sum of two functions whose domains are the same; perhaps there's a separate name for this?


Your function is a map $g:\prod\limits_i X_i\to Y$ given by $g(x) = \sum\limits_if_i(\pi_i(x))$, where $\pi_k:\prod\limits_i X_i\to X_k$ is the canonical projection. You could therefore write $g = \sum\limits_i f_i\circ \pi_i$.
In your specific case with only two index values for $i$, you could explicitly write
$g = f_1\circ\pi_1 + f_2\circ\pi_2$.

Thank your for the more rigorous formulation. Nice to know that the restriction of some element $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ to $X_k$ can be referred to as the canonical projection.
That said, to answer the second question of the post, how would you describe such a function $g$ in plain English? `The sum of two functions' doesn't quite fit, are you aware of conventional phrasing?

You can't get away from the fact that the domain is a product space. So I would say this is a "sum of functions of the individual coordinates" of the points in the domain.

There seem to be a number of people who call such a function of multiple variables an
additively separable function.

That's good to know. I suppose this term wouldn't also apply to functions of the form $g(x_1,x_2,x_3)=f_1(x_1,x_2)+f_2(x_2,x_3)$. Perhaps the latter is worth a different post on the site.
